# How to create rows and columns in latex?

Tags: pdftex

Hi I have my table I need to add this in latex format how I do this . Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: @usmankhan did u have a look at the answer

Comment: @jsbibra thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want verticals use

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|X|}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %Used to color the last column

%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
%\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\columncolor{#2}\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llllllX}
  \hline
  S No& Thesis&Data type 1 & year 2 &publisher3 & author 4 &explanation\\
  \hline
as&sa&as&  item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```